# Deserialize flat array in XML by Jackson to List of Pojo

Tags: java, jackson, pojo, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

Can you help me to parse the following XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="http:/foo.com">
   <date>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</date>
   <element>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Stuart</name>
      <age>34</age>
      <regdate><date>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</date></regdate>
   </element>
   <element>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Lora</name>
      <age>12</age>
      <regdate><date>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</date></regdate>
   </element>
   <element>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>Ben</name>
      <age>50</age>
      <regdate><date>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</date></regdate>
   </element>
</dataset >
```

I tried to create POJO like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "element")
public class ElementXML {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
    private Long id;    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "age")
    private Long age;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "regdate")
    private LocalDateTime regdate;
}
```

and parsing mechanism that I've used is here:

```
    XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    File inputFile = new File("some path");
    XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile));


    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
```

There I am stuck because I don't know how to parse just element tags into a List of my created POJO ElementXML. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

**EDIT** Trace after edited parsing by answers:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1 (through reference chain: com.xml.Dataset["element"]->java.lang.Object[][1])

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:365)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:206)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
    at com.xml.data.ParseXmlTest.test(ParseXmlTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.XmlTokenStream.skipEndElement(XmlTokenStream.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.FromXmlParser.nextToken(FromXmlParser.java:584)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:195)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Your problem is a little tricky because you need to solve a few issues. Let's start to solve them one by one.**

### 1. The model does not fit the `XML` payload.

First of all, you need to create a model which fits your `payload`. It does not depend on the format because for `JSON` and `XML` it will be almost the same. To do that I propose always starting from the serialization process. It is much easier to build the model in `Java` and try to serialize it. In case it does not look the same as expected you need to update the model. You iterate these steps: `update` and `serialise` until you will find the valid model. After that, you can deserialize the given `payload` without any problems.

### 2. Jackson annotations.

Even so `Jackson`'s annotations are great do not use them without a reason. If the `POJO` property is the same as the node name in `XML` you do not need to add the `JacksonXmlProperty` annotation. You must add it when names in `POJO` and `payload` are different. In other cases, this is overcomplicating the `POJO` structure. We should keep it as simple as possible. You need to use one tricky annotation: [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html). It is used when we have collections of nodes but they are unwrapped.

After these two simple paragraphs let's deserialize your case. We need to extend your `POJO` structure and it should look like the below:

```
class Dataset {

    private LocalDateTime date;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Element> elements;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> element) {
        this.elements = element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dataset{" +
                "date=" + date +
                ", element=" + elements +
                '}';
    }
}

class Element {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long age;
    private RegDate regdate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public RegDate getRegdate() {
        return regdate;
    }

    public void setRegdate(RegDate regdate) {
        this.regdate = regdate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ElementXML{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", regdate=" + regdate.getDate() +
                '}';
    }
}

class RegDate {

    private LocalDateTime date;

    public RegDate() {
        this(null);
    }

    public RegDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegDate{" +
                "date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        Dataset dataset = xmlMapper.readValue(jsonFile, Dataset.class);
        dataset.getElements().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
ElementXML{id=1, name='Stuart', age=34, regdate=2017-10-25T09:13:54}
ElementXML{id=2, name='Lora', age=12, regdate=2017-10-25T09:13:54}
ElementXML{id=3, name='Ben', age=50, regdate=2017-10-25T09:13:54}
```

Two extra comments to above code. When you are working with `java.time.*` classes and `Jackson` is good to start from registering `JavaTimeModule` which comes from [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) module. Since we are using it we can instruct it to use `ISO_DATE_TIME` formatting for `LocalDateTime` classes. In other answers you can find example where `JsonFormat` annotation is used. It is also good solution but when all dates have the same format much easier to define it ones.

For more information, read:

- [How do I update RestTemplate to correctly map Java Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676382/how-do-i-update-resttemplate-to-correctly-map-java-dates)
- [Deserializing LocalDateTime with Jackson JSR310 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571587/deserializing-localdatetime-with-jackson-jsr310-module)
- [Could not find artifact Jackson-modules-java8:jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810554/could-not-find-artifact-jackson-modules-java8jar)

Comment: thank you for answer. I tried it and but I got this error while parsing: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "1000-01-01+00:57": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '1000-01-01+00:57' could not be parsed at index 10

Comment: @DenisStephanov, `1000-01-01+00:57` looks like invalid date. What does it represents? What application should do in that case?

Comment: I found out where was problem. I used for another element LocalDateTime but I got LocalDate. I change it, and now I got this error : Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1

Comment: @DenisStephanov, You need to post the stacktrace. Also, if you use `LocalDate` class you need to provide deserialiser for custom date `pattern` like in my example I provided for `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I tried remove elements and keep just 3 objects and it works. When I keep all elements (about 30000) I got END_ELEMENT error :/

Comment: @DenisStephanov, take a look on this [thread](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/226). Do you have a mixed content? Do you have any `Zero Width Character`-es in your `XML`? There is another question on `SO`:[(De)Serialize mixed content with jackson xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531284/deserialize-mixed-content-with-jackson-xml)

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunatelly I found issue in xml file so I can't solve it in application layer.

Comment: @DenisStephanov, I'm glad I could help. It is a very common issue when we are talking about deserialising from any format. In case you will fix `XML` `payload` this answer should help you with deserialising it.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to model the given XML content by only one POJO class.
You will need several POJO classes for modeling your XML contents properly.

For modeling the `<dataset>` root element you need a class, let's call it `Dataset`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "dataset")
public class Dataset {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "date")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<ElementXML> elements;
}
```

Notice in the code above

- The `date` property is annotated with [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) to specify the
  date-time format to be used
- The `elements` is annotated with [`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html)
  to tell the parser to not expect an extra wrapper around the sequence of `<element>`

Next, you need a class for modeling the XML content between `<element>...</element>`,
very much like your `ElementXML` class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ElementXML {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "age")
    private Long age;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "regdate")
    private RegDate regdate;
}
```

Notice in the code above, that you need to model the `regdate` property
more sophisticated.
Because the XML content does not look like `<regdate>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</regdate>`
you cannot simply declare it as `LocalDate regdate`.
Instead the XML looks like `<regdate><date>2017-10-25T09:13:54+02:00</date></regdate>`.
Therefore you need to model it with yet another class (let's call it `RegDate`)

And finally, here is the `RegDate` class for modeling the XML content
between `<regdate>...</regdate>`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RegDate {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "date")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

Notice again the use of `@JsonFormat` to specify the date-time format.

Using the classes above you can parse XML like this

```
    File inputFile = new File("some path");
    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    Dataset dataset = xmlMapper.readValue(inputFile, Dataset.class);
```